# XML parsing C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How do you parse this kind of XML file with LINQ?

```
<houses>
  <house nbr="146" city="Linköping" owner="john"/>
  <house nbr="134" city="Norrköping" owner="wayne"/>
  <house nbr="146" city="Köping" owner="steffe"/>
</houses>
```

All examples I can find only describe how to parse when each element has a value.

If this was the case I would have done it like this:

```
var houses = from house in xmlDoc.Descendants("house")
            select new RowData
            {
                number = spec.Element("nbr").Value,
                city = spec.Element("city").Value,
                owner = spec.Element("owner").Value,
            };
return houses ;
```

But this xml file is not formatted that way.

Comment: What are you looking to get out of it?

Comment: Each element provides a collection of attributes that you can use in a LINQ query. Show us how you read the elements in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var houses = from house in document.Descendants("house")
                select new RowData
                {
                    number = (int)house.Attribute("nbr"),
                    city = (string)house.Attribute("city"),
                    owner = (string)house.Attribute("owner")
                };
```